# MEAN.JS | Angular directive for changing content when Item is selected in <select>

Tags: angularjs

I've tried to write a directive, which binds to my  tag and when I select a item in the selector, the directive checks which item is selected and modifies the DOM in a determined way..., for example adding the content of a html into the DOM.

Unfortunatly I just cant achieve that its working. Can somebody help me please?

This is a snippet of the html view

```
<div class="form-group" show-errors>
      <label class="control-label" for="fields[class]">Starting Class</label>
      <select ng-change="change()" name="fields[class]" data-ng-model="vm.class.selectedClass" id="class" class="form-control" ascendancy required>  
        <option value="marauder">Marauder</option>
        <option value="ranger">Ranger</option>
        <option value="shadow">Shadow</option>
        <option value="witch">Witch</option>
        <option value="templar">Templar</option>
        <option value="duelist">Duelist</option>
        <option value="scion">Scion</option>
      </select>
      <div ng-messages="vm.form.buildForm.class.$error" role="alert">
        <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Class is required.</p>
      </div>
</div>
<ascend>Here comes the "......."</ascend>
```

This is the directive im trying to use to listen on a "select" in the selector

```html
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('builds')
    .directive('ascendancy', ascendancy);

  ascendancy.$inject = [/*Example: '$state', '$window' */];

  function ascendancy(/*Example: $state, $window */) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        // Ascendancy directive logic
        // ...

        element.text('this is the ascendancy directive');
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

The directive is freshly generated by the yo directive generator.
I would like to achieve the following behaviour:

when a item in the selector gets selected, I want to display HTML in the ascend tag. The HTML is different for each selector option.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Someone indeed can help you. But not us, unless you add some code and show what have you tried so far.

Comment: The code I got is basicly a copy paste of the angular website directive tutorials. I cant understand how this would help someone.

Comment: We can't tell you why your code isn't working if you won't show us your code. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In order to provide a solution, we need a full description of the problem. That includes, what you are trying to accomplish, a description of what the code did, and a description of why this does not achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve it...

build.client.controller.js

```html
....

   vm.authentication = Authentication;
vm.build = build;
vm.error = null;
vm.form = {};
vm.remove = remove;
vm.save = save;

$scope.classList = [{
  'classid': 1,
  'name': 'Marauder',
  'ascendancies': [{
    'ascendancyid': 1,
    'name': 'Berserker'
    }, {
    'ascendancyid': 2,
    'name': 'Chieftain'
    }, {
    'ascendancyid': 3,
    'name': 'Juggernaut'
  }]
}, {
  'classid': 2,
  'name': 'Ranger',
  'ascendancies':[{
    'ascendancyid': 1,
    'name': 'Deadeye'
  }, {
    'ascendancyid': 2,
    'name': 'Raider'
  }, {
    'ascendancyid': 3,
    'name': 'Pathfinder'
  }],
}, {
  'classid': 3,
  'name': 'Shadow',
  'ascendancies':[{
    'ascendancyid': 1,
    'name': 'Assassin'
  }, {
    'ascendancyid': 2,
    'name': 'Saboteur'
  }, {
    'ascendancyid': 3,
    'name': 'Trickster'
  }]
}, {
  'classid': 4,
  'name': 'Witch',
  'ascendancies':[{
    'ascendancyid': 1,
    'name': 'Necromancer'
  }, {
    'ascendancyid': 2,
    'name': 'Elementalist'
  }, {
    'ascendancyid': 3,
    'name': 'Occultist'
  }]
}, {
  'classid': 5,
  'name': 'Templar',
  'ascendancies':[{
    'ascendancyid': 1,
    'name': 'Inquisitor'
  }, {
    'ascendancyid': 2,
    'name': 'Hierophant'
  }, {
    'ascendancyid': 3,
    'name': 'Guardian'
  }]
}, {
  'classid': 6,
  'name': 'Duelist',
  'ascendancies': [{
    'ascendancyid': 1,
    'name': 'Slayer'
  }, {
    'ascendancyid': 2,
    'name': 'Gladiator'
  }, {
    'ascendancyid': 3,
    'name': 'Champion'
  }]
}, {
  'classid': 7,
  'name': 'Scion',
  'ascendancies':[{
    'ascendancyid': 1,
    'name': 'Ascendant'
  }]
}];

$scope.getAscendancies = function () {
  if ($scope.classSelected.classid > '0')
    $scope.showAscendancy = true;
}
....
```

form-build.client.view.html

```
<div class="form-group" show-errors>
      <label class="control-label" ng-model="ascendancySelected" ng-show='showAscendancy'>Ascendancy</label>            
      <select ng-show='showAscendancy' name="ascendancy" ng-options="ascendancy.name for ascendancy in classSelected.ascendancies" ng-model="ascendancySelected" class="form-control" required></select>
          <div ng-messages="vm.form.buildForm.class.$error" role="alert">
        <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Ascendancy is required.</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```